# BCryptHelper.HashPassword .NET equivalent PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

Recently I tried hashing the password in php which uses the same algorithm as the .net script below:

```
private const string key = "#lDtp#4S$cVq9Ef2#bAAw)g1bR=DwC4jG"; //hard coded key

public static string HashPasswordPreSalt(string password)
{
    string hashedPassword = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(password + key, "$2a$10$TZdpQbTJhQAEhk72eEBWYO");
    return hashedPassword;
}
```

**The result of the output**

```
$2a$10$TZdpQbTJhQAEhk72eEBWYOwZPnI7vOObFmzDk6JPxquLkJLY3VO1O

password:123 key: #lDtp#4S$cVq9Ef2#bAAw)g1bR=DwC4jG
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me you can use the PHP crypt function with CRYPT_BLOWFISH support (look at the examples on http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: CRYPT('123#lDtp#4S$cVq9Ef2#bAAw)g1bR=DwC4jG', '$2a$10$TZdpQbTJhQAEhk72eEBWYO'); Result Output : $2a$10$TZdpQbTJhQAEhk72eEBWYOwGg0zCWNZrK7xm6l4h.1DXc0WdOcIW. Different output result from question i asked above :(